# Trouble using UILocalizedIndexedCollation to filter a table view with the inputed user's name.

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, sorting, swift4

I'm new to this forum! I am having a little bit of trouble sorting my Person's array with the use of UILocalizedIndexedCollation.

### Code

I created the following class:

```
@objc class Person : NSObject {
    @objc var firstName: String!
    @objc var lastName: String!

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

}
```

With the help of this class, I created a bunch of instances to be displayed and sorted alphabetically on the table view by their last names.

For me to do so, I created the following function:

```
func partitionObjects(array:[AnyObject], collationStringSelector:Selector) -> ([AnyObject], [String]) {
        var unsortedSections = [[AnyObject]]()

        //1. Create a array to hold the data for each section
        for _ in self.sectionTitles {
            unsortedSections.append([]) //appending an empty array
        }
        //2. Put each objects into a section
        for item in array {
            let index:Int = self.section(for: item, collationStringSelector:collationStringSelector)
            unsortedSections[index].append(item)
        }
        //3. sorting the array of each sections
        var sectionTitles = [String]()
        var sections = [AnyObject]()
        sectionTitles.append("Frequently Requested")


        for index in 0 ..< unsortedSections.count { if unsortedSections[index].count > 0 {

            sectionTitles.append(self.sectionTitles[index])
            sections.append(self.sortedArray(from: unsortedSections[index], collationStringSelector: collationStringSelector) as AnyObject)
            }
        }

        return (sections, sectionTitles)
    }
```

With this function, I am able to assign my array of `Person` and array of titles to the returning values of the function:

```
var sectionTitles = [Person]()
var personsWithSections = [[Person]]()
var contacts = [Person]()

 @objc func setUpCollation(){

        let (arrayPersons, arrayTitles) = collation.partitionObjects(array: self.persons, collationStringSelector: #selector(getter: Person.lastName))

        self.personsWithSections = arrayPersons as! [[Person]]
        self.sectionTitles = arrayTitles
    }
```

With this, I am able able to set up my whole table view and it works great. I get every person sorted up by their last name to their corresponding alphabetical section.

### **The Issue, Specifically**

The problem is that if the user has only inputed their first name and not their last name, that `Person` object gets appended to the last section of the array, where objects with last names that start with numbers or special characters go.

> How can I append these object's with only first names to the corresponding alphabetical
>   section if the user doesn't input a last name? The same goes with
>   numbers.

As you can see, my collationsStringSelector takes Person.lastName, I was thinking maybe I could create a computed variable that would return the right person's property under some conditions? I am not sure how I would do so. It would be nice to have some guidance or help!

**ps:** NEW to the forum! if I'm doing something wrong let me know guys! thanks